# download and install cassandra for windows 8.1

Tags: database, cassandra

I can't successful download and install cassandra database for win.
I go to http://cassandra.apache.org/download/ and try for download. download is success but I don't understand what should I do.
And I try download CQLSH, but I can not use from CQL shell.
I need help for this problem.
How to install?
How to use cqlsh?

Comment: some googling could have helped, anyways see this http://www.datastax.com/2012/01/getting-started-with-apache-cassandra-on-windows-the-easy-way